# Basis for space of matrices in $\mathbb M_2(\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given that $G=\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & -a\\
b & c
\end{array}\right):a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\right\} $ and $H=\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
x & y\\
z & -z
\end{array}\right):x,y,z\in R\right\} $ are matrices in  $\mathbb M_2(\mathbb{R)}$.

(1) Find a basis for $G$.

(2) Find a basis for $H$

(3) Find a basis for $G\cap H$

For the first two of these could be argue that since both of the matrices

are subsets of $\mathbb M_2(\mathbb R)$that a basis for each of the
matrices would be the standard basis for

$\mathbb M_2(\mathbb R)$ ie $\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\right\} $?.

For the intersection of $G$ and $H$

I am unsure what a basis would be ?

Comment: Can you find a basis for $\{(a,-a,b,c)\colon a,b,c\in \mathbb R\}$ and see why your answer is wrong?

Comment: I thought the standard basis would suffice ?

Comment: Are you stating that the standard basis is a basis of $\{(a,-a,b,c)\colon a,b,c\in \mathbb R\}$?

Comment: Yes thats what i would have thought.

Comment: OK, this is helpful. You don't know what a basis is. Do you know the difference between a basis and a set of generators?

Comment: Well i know a basis is supposed to be a set of linearly independent vectors that in combination can represent any vector in a given vector space, Thats why i thought the standard basis for M2(R) would have sufficed for the first two, but I'm unsure that a set of generators are? .

Comment: How do we find them ?

Comment: Almost right, but there's something missing and it makes a huge difference. "In combination can represent any vector in a given vector space", but also any combination of the vectors in the basis must be in the vector space and the standard basis doesn't fulfill this. There are combinations of the vectors in the standard basis which aren't in the vector space.

Comment: is the vector space R or M2(R)?.

Comment: The vector space is a subset of $\mathcal M_2(\mathbb R)$, namely $G$ or $H$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: How many independent parameters do you have for each set?

I'll complete it if you need more help.

**First edit:**

For example, for $G$, you can write each element in $G$ like this $$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & -a\\
b & c
\end{array}\right) = a \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)+b \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)+ c \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

Therefore, the set $\{\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right),\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right),\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)  \}$ spans $G$. You can show that these matrices are also linearly independent, it's easy to see that. Therefore they form a basis for $G$.

Can you do the same for $H$ and find a basis for it?

Can you see what kind of matrices will lie in $H \cap G$?

**Second edit:**

Well, if something lies in both $G$ and $H$, then it must have the forms of elements in both sets.

So, if $A$ is in $G \cap H$ we can find $a,b,c,x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$A= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & -a\\
b & c
\end{array}\right)=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
x & y\\
z & -z
\end{array}\right)$$

Since the two matrices are equal, we realize that $A$ must look like this:

$$A=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
x & -x\\
z & -z
\end{array}\right)$$

Therefore:

$$G \cap H = \{ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
x & -x\\
z & -z
\end{array}\right): x,z \in \mathbb{R} \}$$

Can you find a basis for $G \cap H$ now?

Comment: Do we only need two ? .

Comment: @Massin: Well, for $G$ you need three parameters, for $H$ you need $3$ parameters as well. For their intersection, generally speaking, sometimes you can use the formula $\dim(G+H)=\dim G+\dim H−\dim(G \cap H)$, but sometimes you need to find their intersection first and then see how many parameters you need to describe the elements in $G \cap H$. In this particular problem, following the second approach is easy. If I need to explain more clearly, tell me.

Comment: Howcould we tell the matrix in H intersection G